# How to accept user input in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to accept user input to allow the user to name the players in my game. I am reading the documentation on entry but everything I am finding refers to OnTextChanged, etc. I want the user to be able to enter a name for player 1 and a name for player 2 and have the corresponding fields set to whatever strings the user inputs only when they click a button on the page called StartGame. What am I missing here?

xml (I know theres very cleary stuff missing where ive added entry but I am confused on how to handle this)

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <!--<Label Text="Player 1 Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium"/>-->
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter a name for Player 1"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter a name for Player 2"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" 
                Text="Start"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

code behind

```
namespace SampleApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NameEntryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NameEntryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace SampleApp.ViewModels
{
public class NameEntryPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    public Command StartGameCommand { get; set; }


    public NameEntryPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        StartGameCommand = new Command(() => StartGame());

    }

    private void StartGame()
    {

        this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.TwoPlayerPage());
    }

}
}
```

Model

```
namespace SampleApp.Models
{
public class Player 
{

    public int LifeTotal { get; set; }


    public string Name { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: It seems your problem has been solved in another question.

Answer (score 0):

in your ViewModel, add properties for your players

```
Player Player1 { get; set; } = new Player();
Player Player2 { get; set; } = new Player();
```

then in your XAML, bind the `Entry` to the player names

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter a name for Player 1" Text="{Binding Player1.Name}" />
<Entry Placeholder="Enter a name for Player 2" Text="{Binding Player2.Name}" />
```

finally, in your code-behind be sure to set the `BindingContext`

```
NameEntryPageViewModel ViewModel {get;set;}

public NameEntryPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext = ViewModel = new NameEntryPageViewModel();
}
```

alternatively, you can assign a `x:Name` property to your entries and then just get the user input using `MyControlName.Text`

Comment: I dont actually create my players until the user navigates to the next page (the page that hosts the actual game) so I need to follow your alternative suggestion. However, after naming my entry "EntryNameP1" I am still not able to access it from my NameEntryPageViewModel

Comment: you can only access controls from the code behind, not the VM.  You can just create string properties in your VM for Player1Name and Player2Name.

Comment: ok I think I have that figured out now. However, now my NameEntryPage will not display at all. I will post a new question so i can show the code I am running